# Place an image and let it align right in a merged cell using NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

As title.  My goal is to put a company logo on my excel so it can be shown at the lower-right corner of a paper. Assume that the `CompanyImageRawData` stores the byte array of the company logo, and `_IWorkbook` is my excel body.

```
private void Cert_PageLowerCompanyImageDeploy(ref IRow LowerRow,int ColL=0,int ColR = 3)
        {
            int iCompanyImageIndex = _IWorkbook.AddPicture(CompanyImageRawData, PictureType.PNG);
            LowerRow.Height = 1800;
            LowerRow.Sheet.AddMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(LowerRow.RowNum, LowerRow.RowNum, 0, ColR));
            ICell ClImageArea = LowerRow.CreateCell(0);
            ClImageArea.CellStyle = new ExcelCellStyle
            {
                TextAlignLR = HorizontalAlignment.Center
            }.CreateCellstyle(ref _IWorkbook);
            ICreationHelper helper = _IWorkbook.GetCreationHelper();
            IDrawing drawing = LowerRow.Sheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();
            IClientAnchor anchor = helper.CreateClientAnchor();
            anchor.AnchorType = AnchorType.MoveAndResize;
            anchor.Col1 = ColL;//0 index based column
            anchor.Col2 = ColR;
            anchor.Row1 = LowerRow.RowNum;//0 index based row
            anchor.Row2 = LowerRow.RowNum;
            IPicture picture = drawing.CreatePicture(anchor, iCompanyImageIndex);
            picture.Resize(0.7, 1);
            anchor.Dx2 = 0;
        }
```

But my comapny logo is shown at the lower-left corner in my excel not at lower-right.  Could someone guide me to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `Col1` & `Col2` properties to `ColR` should fix it

```
 anchor.Col1 = ColR;
 anchor.Col2 = ColR;
```